# How can i get a video views with Facebook API

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-insights

1. I want to get the number of views of a video (of public pages), i
   already tried /VIDEO_ID/video_insights/total_video_views/ but it's
   not giving any data all i get is : {   "data": [   ] }

   With the new version of Facebook API (v3.2 ,v3.3 ,v4 ) it's getting
   more complicated to get video insights.

Comment: You can not get that kind of insights data for videos from arbitrary public pages, you need to have admin access to the page.

Comment: Too bad , because i can get the likes, comments,.. but not the views.
Thank you!

Comment: If anybody has an alternative way to get them i'm all ears ....

Comment: There is no official to get this via API.